# ssh quick clean written symbols at unix console without backspaces

Tags: unix, ssh, console

While working with ssh I sometimes write to long string/commands eg. `command -param 3 4 5 7 3 paran faff gfd werg h tgr egr`

How to quickly clean it without tons of backspaces and without execution of command. 
thanks

Comment: @bmargulies what? Any user console when you written commands on it.

Comment: @bmargulies make it clean = without symbols. Have you ever worked with console?? check the answers below. they do exactly what I want. does not know why you -1 and vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need `CTRL + u`, because that is simplest way to clear the command line.

Comment: You're welcome. You can find a lot of usefull tips about bash here: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))

Comment: thanks! vote for my thread, please, does not know why user  bmargulies give it -1 and now delete all comments, but not his vote :(

Comment: Nice one Vall. I thought it was a good little question abrahab.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-C works in Bash on a Mac.